# interchanging rows and columns of a 4D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, transpose

I have 117 rows and 147 columns of data. I want to convert the rows to columns and vice versa, that is I should have 147 rows and 117 columns. I tried the function `.'` and `'` and even the `transpose`, `permute` functions. However, I haven't been successful. I get an error saying

> Transpose on ND array is not defined. Use PERMUTE instead

Please can someone help me if they know how I can achieve this. Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
whos AA_03:
Name Size Bytes Class Attributes
AA_O3 4-D 1651104 single
```

Comment: It is saying that you have an N dimensional Array, type in command `whos YourDataMatrix` what do you get?

Comment: yeah, your matrix is 4Dimensional, how do you want to transpose it?

Comment: You have a 4 dimensional array. The transpose is not mathematically defined for that. Which dimensions do you wish to interchange?

Comment: The data is 4-D (lat,long,vertical,time). in the vertical though its only one level.

Comment: That comment made no sense.What do you mean only one level?

Comment: i am also looking at the first hour so basically t is also 1, and i have 117X147 of data, which i wish to convert to 147x117

Comment: by one level i mean just the surface level data..

Comment: so its 117x147x1x1 and i need to change to 147x117x1x1 .. is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transpose` could also be described as "swapping first and second dimension", and that is what I understand you want to do. The error message suggests to use `permute` which is the solution:

```
permute(AA_03,[2,1,3,4])
```